# Angular Mat AutoComplete doesn't display/show drop down list of returned Object from Back End

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I've tried to implement mat autocomplete (Angular Material) and the .TS code works and return Data from my Back end API.
BUT the autocomplete doesn't show the object automatically on the drop down list.

Follow my code:

```js
export class VendaComponent implements OnInit {

  public produtoAutoComplete: Observable<Produtos> = null;
  public vendaForm = new FormControl();
  vendas: Venda[] = [];
  produtos:Produtos;
  isLoading = false;

  constructor(private vendasService: VendaService, private produtoService: ProdutoService, private toastr: ToastrService) { }

  lookup(value: string): Observable<Produtos> {
    return this.produtoService.search(value.toLowerCase()).pipe(
      // map the item property of the github results as our return object
      map(results => results.produtos),
      // catch errors
      catchError(_ => {
        return of(null);
      })
    );
  }
 
  ngOnInit() {
    this.produtoAutoComplete = this.vendaForm.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      // delay emits
      debounceTime(300),
      //map(options => options ? this.filter(options) : this.produtos.slice())      
      switchMap(value => {
        if (value !== '') {
          // lookup from github
          return this.lookup(value);
        } else {
          // if no value is pressent, return null
          return of(null);
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

Service code:

```js
const API_URL = environment.apiUrl;

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }), responseType: 'text' as 'json'
};


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProdutoService {
  private produtoUrl = API_URL + 'produto/';  // URL to web api
  dataChange: BehaviorSubject<Produto[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Produto[]>([]);
  // Temporarily stores data from dialogs
  dialogData: any;
  produtos: Produto[] = [];
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
```

And my html:

```html
 <form class="example-form">
          <mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
            <input matInput type="text" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="vendaForm" [matAutocomplete]="auto">

            <mat-placeholder class="placeholder">Search</mat-placeholder>

            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let option of produtoAutoComplete | async" [value]="option.descProduto">
                {{option.descProduto}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
          </mat-form-field>
        </form>
```

I've tried everything, follow thousands of examples and nothing works. Like i said the service works and return my JSON, my problem is when I try to display the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a lot of hours I found a solution for this question.

TS of Component:

```js
export class VendaComponent implements OnInit {

  public vendaForm = new FormControl();
  vendas: Venda[] = [];
  results: any[];
  isLoading = false;

  constructor(private vendasService: VendaService, private produtoService: ProdutoService, private toastr: ToastrService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.vendaForm.valueChanges.subscribe(
      term => {
        if (term != '') {
          this.produtoService.search1(term).subscribe(
            data => {
              this.results = data as any[];
              console.log(data);
            })
        }
      })
  }
```

Data Service:

```js
search1(term) {
    const params = new HttpParams()
      .set('descProduto', term)
      .set('codigoBarras', '123');//Hardcode parameter just for tests
      var listOfBooks= this.httpClient.get(this.produtoUrl + 'busca/', { params })
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(500),  // WAIT FOR 500 MILISECONDS ATER EACH KEY STROKE.
        map(
          (data: any) => {
            return (
              data.length != 0 ? data as any[] : [{ "Produto": "No Record Found" } as any]
            );
          }
        ));
    return listOfBooks;
  }
```

HTML to display the Material AutoComplete:

```html
<form>
          <mat-form-field class="container">

            <!-- ADD AN INPUT BOX OF TYPE TEXT AND LINK IT TO THE AUTO COMPLETE PANEL. -->
            <input type="text" placeholder="Procure Produtos ..." matInput [formControl]="vendaForm" [matAutocomplete]="auto">

            <!-- CREATE AUTO COMPLETE PANEL WITH OPTIONS. -->
            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let result of results" [value]="result.descProduto">
                {{ result.descProduto }}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>

          </mat-form-field>
        </form>
```

I hope it help somebody.